# Is there a cleaner way to implement a Multi-tenant database with the following requirements?

Tags: sql, database-design, multi-tenant

I have been working with Salesforce.com for several years, and for a mental exercise/challenge I've tried to come up with a similar solution to how they handle their "database" (Yes I know they aren't really using tables and view, but Metadata).  This turned out to be much more challenging then first anticipated.

Please keep in mind I am not trying to re-invent SFDC.  I was just trying to explore solutions to multi-tenant implementations.

Requirements

1. Must be able to handle multiple customers/tenants with out exposing customer specific data to other customers and without using customer specific databases.
2. All customers must have a standardized access to a set of standard tables (i.e.  Select * from Account returns all the Accounts associated with requesting customer)
3. All customers must be able to add custom fields to all Standard tables.
4. All customers must be able to add custom tables.
5. Any customer's custom fields must only be visible to that customer, even if "added" to a standard table.
6. Any customer's custom table must only be visible to that customer.
7. Ideally this solution will not be specific to one RDBMS. (Can't rely on PostgreSQL's search_path)

My Solution

1. Create a multi-schema database design, where the standard tables are stored in the "Primary" schema (`Primary.TrueAccounts`).
2. For each customer create a separate schema with base tables to hold a FK linking them back to the `Primary.TrueAccounts` (`Cust1.AccountCustomFields`).  This table is where any Custom Fields will be added.
3. A customer's custom tables will only be added to their schema.
4. For each Standard table create a view in the customers Schema left joining the Standard columns with that customer's custom columns (`CREATE VIEW Cust1.Accounts AS SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.* FROM Primary.TrueAccounts AS t1 LEFT JOIN Cust1.AccountCustomFields AS t2 ON t1.id = tw.Accountid WHERE t1.CustomerId = 1`)

I have mocked this basic solution up in MySQL workbench, so I know it at least is possible as described.

My ultimate question is "How did I do?".  Is there a Better/Standard/less ugly/more efficient way of accomplishing the requirements as laid out above?

Comment: You should be aware that in some SQL products, the view definition is fixed when it's created, so you need to do some work to refresh the view when new columns are added (`select *` wont pick up the new columns)

Comment: That would definitely break my goals ... Thanks for the insight

Comment: Are you limited to MySQL? In PostgreSQL you could solve the "view problem" by using table functions that build the select on the fly (although I don't know how well that would perform with larger databases)

Comment: I hope that my solution would be equally applicable to PostgreSQL as it is to MySQL (MSSQL for that matter too).  Overall I am hoping to stay away from solutions that would only be possible in a single RDBMS.